# Why my mobile can't reach server while my PC can when they use the same ReactApp?

Tags: reactjs, mobile, fetch, fastapi, raspberry-pi4

Im hosting python (FastApi) server and ReactApp client on RaspberryPi 4B (OS: Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster) - inb4: i must to use older OS because some packages which are crucial for me are still not working on newest Raspberry Pi OS).

So i got 3 devices connected to the same WiFi network:

- RaspberryPi Host- which hosts FastApi python server and client ReactApp.
- PC client (Windows 11).
- Mobile client (Realme GT, Android 12).

When Im going to the ReactApp website `http://<<raspberrypi_IP>>:3000` with PC or Mobile i can see my React website properly, but:

- When I use it with my PC (via any browser) -  Client successfully connects to the server and server handles my request perfectly
- When i use my mobile (via any browser) - I got `failed to fetch`

My fetch request:

```
    async function call_api(command) {
        try {
            const response = await fetch(`http://raspberrypi:8000/api/${command}`, {
                method: 'GET',
                headers: {
                    accept: 'application/json',
                },
            })
            if (!response.ok) {
                console.error(`Error! status:  ${response.status}`);
            }

            const result_json = await response.json();
            console.log(result_json)
            return result_json;
        } catch (err) {
            console.error('Error:', err);
            alert(err) # to be visible on mobile
        }
    }
```

I thought it was CORS, but it is not. For debug i set whole server like this:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware

app = FastAPI()

origins = [
    "http://raspberrypi:3000", # 'raspberrypi' is reference to localhost of RaspberryPi (but using 'localhost' won't work) 
    "http://<<PC_IP>>:3000",
    "http://<<MOBLIE_IP>>:3000"
]

app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=origins,
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)

@app.get("/api/{action}")
async def control(action: str):
    return {'action': action, 'success': True}
```

And problem still occurs. I don't see what else could vary between these devices

Does mobiles are handling ReactApps in some other way that may cause difference?

Comment: Are you actually trying to call `fetch` on `http://localhost:8000`? I'm guessing you're never hitting the API endpoint on the pi on your desktop, just your locally running API endpoint - `localhost` would be just the mobile browser trying to contact another endpoint _on the mobile phone_.

Comment: Oh i made a mistake - it is not `localhost` but `raspberrypi` (name of the host which is reference to RPi4B IP - set by Raspbian automatically)

Comment: But anyway - I use the same app with PC and it is working properly. Does mobiles hit it differently?